# Ubuntu 14.04 Python 2.7 still default, set 3.x as default

Tags: python

Please set 3.x Python as default in 14.04, currently even writing python in terminal starts 2.7

Comment: It seems you're trying to file a bug or feature request. Please see [the community bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). You may also want to look at [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121). I recommend searching aggressively on Launchpad before filing a new report, as this seems like a topic of considerable interest and there may already be a report (which you could "sign on to" with the "affects me" link, and if applicable, comment w/additional useful information). Or *discuss* at http://discourse.ubuntu.com/ or http://ubuntuforums.org/.

Comment: I'm running patched Ubuntu Studio 14.04 Beta 1 and the command "python --version" returns Python 2.7.6.  I'm pretty sure this is what was being questioned.

Answer (score 4):

This is not exactly an answer to your question, but a workaround, just in case you need it. python3 comes installed by default on Ubuntu 14.04. So the best way you can start python3 when you type `python` on the terminal is opening your `~/.bash_aliases` file and typing this:

```
alias python='python3`
```

and then doing a `source ~/.bash_aliases`. You'll get python3 when you type `python` on your terminal hereon.